# Vue.js two-way binding doesn't work when I change the state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

Here is my problem. I have a dynamic array "slots" of objects that looks like this:
`[{"availability": 1},{"availability: 3}]`
Then i render a bunch of inputs in vue js using v-for:
`<div v-for="slot in array"><input v-model="slot.availability></input></div>`
And then I add a watcher to track whether one of objects increased it's value more than 10. If so return it to 10 like this:

```
watch: {
  slots: {
    handler() {
      this.slots.forEach(slot => {
        if (slot.availability > 10) slot.availability = 10;
      });
    },
    deep: true
  }
}
```

But it work only first time. For example if I type 99 it returns to 10 and the if I continue typiny 9 nothing happens it doesn't change 109 to 10. It only changes back to 10 when i click away from input.
I suppose there is a way to fix it using computed prop, but I don't know how. I'd be greatfull for any help!

Comment: works ok in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-meninsky-g8mzgr?file=/src/App.vue).  do you have any errors in your browser's dev console that pop up before or after you try setting the input value?  whatever the issue it most likely lies somewhere else outside of the code you've posted so far.

Comment: Nope, no errors at all.

Comment: If you can provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that would be the best way to receive additional help.  The code provided so far _should_ work but obviously something else is causing your issue.  If you can find what other code is necessary to reproduce the issue please add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works also good with `Vue v3`. There is no problem.

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue 

const data  = [{"availability": 1}, {"availability": 5}, {"availability": 3}]

const App = {
  setup() {
    const slots = ref(data);    
    return { slots }
  },
  watch: {
    slots: {
      handler() {
        this.slots.forEach(slot => {
          if (slot.availability > 10) slot.availability = 10;
        });
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
   slots: {{slots}}
   <div v-for="slot in slots">
      <input v-model="slot.availability" />
   </div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```